# Optimize element locator relative to other one

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have a HTML element:

```
<div class="L6SDZKszCG_ZE8mz8YoU A5Cr6bSu9aHPbpHz2CJD" data-test-id="test-element-table-row">
<div class="uR__axC81ElKcEfLKwNQ">
    <div class="nTODXyNgcTJM6eGt3_9B">
        <img data-test-id="thumbnail-image"
             src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/someBase64Line"
             alt="Some Output"/>
    <div class="jDvpilNE5rp5IbTvzosR">00:00</div>
</div>
<div class="UQumEmFQetFjm9i8pajl">
    <div class="T32Zz26iJTmFPm3QCP2y">
        <div class="JmXuiR3SP1pqGA0QKrsV">test element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="v192ycS57h4qcwn8dB4k">
        <div class="JmXuiR3SP1pqGA0QKrsV">Text1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="KdcP4eejotpiqTJfD0Ee">
        <div class="JmXuiR3SP1pqGA0QKrsV">Text2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="k2YcTO_adf66wXfntaUO">
    <div class="k2YcTO_adf66wXfntaUO">
        <img src="././file/929cd3158fc3b848a1e9.svg"
                alt="Primary Icon">
            <div class="_3TsZ4BgwHNiRL8pA7Bs">
                <div class=""/>
                <div class="e3s4o2xP55M4yZYLaQh6"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I've found out a way to get a locator for the element with data-test-id='thumbnail-image', but in relation to the element that contains text 'test element 1', which is:

```
public getThumbnailForTableRowName(tableRowName: string): Locator {
  const thumbnailLocator = this.page.getByTestId(`test-element-table-row`)
  .getByText(tableRowName, { exact: true })
  .locator(`xpath=../../..`)
  .getByTestId(`thumbnail-image`)

  return thumbnailLocator;
}
```

I have a feeling that it's not optimal and out of good practices though. Is there a better way to get this locator using Playwright locator methods?

Answer (score 0):

Using [getByRole](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-role), you can get the image locator, then scope down by using the test-id:

```js
this.page.getByRole('img').getByTestId('thumbnail-image')
```

Comment: The thing is there are multiple elements with data-test-id="test-element-table-row", so the only way to look for the correct one is to search by text; adding an index to element is also not a case, because their sequence may vary. Moreover, "Text1" and "Text2" may change in time, so `this.page.getByTestId('test-element-table-row').getByText('test element 1 Text1 Text2' {exact: true}) is out of options too.

Comment: I see, in the perfect world, a test-id is unique, but I suppose that is not an option. Not able to test this myself, but maybe by using the .and() method can help you avoid that flaky xpath? 
`public getThumbnailForTableRowName(tableRowName: string): Locator { const thumbnailLocator = this.page.getByTestId('test-element-table-row').and(this.page.getByText(tableRowName, { exact: true })).and(this.page.getByTestId('thumbnail-image')); return thumbnailLocator; }`